# How to tell GCC to emit a specific debugging symbol named by me?

Tags: c, debugging, gcc

I am writing a stateful scanner and I want to have a debugging symbol for every state change.

In my code I call a macro `SETSTATE(ST_xxx)` for instance, which does some nasty things, BUT I could easily also tell GCC to emit at that point a specific debugging symbol based on that name `ST_xxx`.

What I need to accomplish is setting a breakpoint in gdb.

I suppose it should be a `#pragma` or something.

If I only knew how ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I might misunderstand the question,
how about making a dummy function and calling that in `SETSTATE`,
then setting a breakpoint in that function?
For example:

```
void dummy_breakpoint() {}

#define SETSTATE(st) dummy_breakpoint(); ...usual process...
```

Setting `break dummy_breakpoint` in `.gdbinit` might help some labor savings.

**EDIT:**
How about setting a watch-point in `SETSTATE` like the following, and
setting `watch dummy_variable` in `.gdbinit`?

```
char dummy_variable; /* global variable */

#define SETSTATE(st) ++ dummy_variable; ...usual process...
```

However, this might make the program's execution be slower if your
environment doesn't provide hardware watch-point...

Comment: You've got my question right, and having a dummy function like that was also my first thought. Unfortunately that's not possible, because SETSTATE would be used inside the scanner (another function), and it's not possible to have functions within functions, is it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want debugging symbols as a point of reference, you can use labels to create these (just make sure they aren't stripped out of the debug info if unreferenced), though having never used used gdb i'm not sure if it'll pick up labels like ollydbg does with obj scanning/analysis. but seeing as its breakpoints your after, why not just use  a debug trap, like msvc's `__debugbreak()`?, something from here might be of use for the gcc variant: [Is there a portable equivalent to DebugBreak()/__debugbreak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173618/is-there-a-portable-equivalent-to-debugbreak-debugbreak)

Answer (score -1):

On compile use -D ST_xxx

I use this for enabling debugging messages, using macros. It defines the constant ST_xxx with value 1.

Comment: What I need to accomplish is to set a breakpoint in gdb. This doesn't help me in that matter.