# How do I set a software breakpoint on an ARM processor?

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, arm

How do I do the equivalent of an x86 software interrupt:

```
asm( "int $3" )
```

on an ARM processor (specifically a Cortex A8) to generate an event that will break execution under gdb?

Comment: Using the BKPT instruction generates a SIGBUS that seems to mess up the program counter.

Comment: use the swi instruction, I believe svc is another name for that instruction depending on which flavor of arm.

Comment: The SWI instruction is OS/debugger dependent. The Angel debugger defines code 0x18 as ReportException, and subcode 0x20020 as breakpoint. It's not portable. http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0058d/BACBEFAA.html

Comment: See this posted answer which provides a list of alternatives for both ARM and Intel processors, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49079078/1466970 .

Answer (score 28):

Using arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe cross compiler, this works great for me (thanks to Igor's answer):

```
__asm__("BKPT");
```

Answer (score 22):

ARM does not define a specific breakpoint instruction. It can be different in different OSes. On ARM Linux it's usually an UND opcode (e.g. `FE DE FF E7`) in ARM mode and BKPT (`BE BE`) in Thumb.

With GCC compilers, you can usually use `__builtin_trap()` intrinsic to generate a platform-specific breakpoint. Another option is `raise(SIGTRAP)`.

Comment: **GCC/clang assume that code after `__builtin_trap()` is unreachable, even at `-O0`**.  On https://godbolt.org/z/RNc7kY, we can see that for ARM, there's nothing after `.inst   0xe7f000f0`, not even a `bx lr` at the end of a function.  And on x86, it compiles to `ud2` (illegal instruction), again leaving out code to implement later C statements.  Even at `-O0`, ARM gcc8.2 still leaves out function epilogues, although there is code for a later C statement.  But that makes it unusable.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I'd suggest putting it under a run-time condition then.

Comment: @yfr24493AzzrggAcom you can ask a new question about it

Comment: Hi friend I already did that but didn't get a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61649711/how-to-put-breakpoint-with-ptrace-by-address

Answer (score 8):

I have a simple library ([scottt/debugbreak](https://github.com/scottt/debugbreak)) just for this:

```
#include <debugbreak.h>
...
debug_break();
```

Just copy the single `debugbreak.h` header into your code and it'll correctly handle ARM, AArch64, i386, x86-64 and even MSVC.

Answer (score 8):

`__asm__ __volatile__ ("bkpt #0");`

See [BKPT](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABHCHGB.html) man entry.

Comment: You don't need `volatile` if your assembly doesn't take args.

Comment: @L29Ah: Without `volatile`, the compiler reordered the location of my breakpoint.  That's bad...

Answer (score 3):

For Windows on ARM, the instrinsic `__debugbreak()` still works which utilizes undefined opcode.

```
nt!DbgBreakPointWithStatus:
defe     __debugbreak
```

Comment: Looks like `__debugbreak()` is an intrinsic available for "x86, x64, ARM, ARM64" and whose use requires the `intrin.h` include file., [topic __debugbreak in Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/debugbreak?view=msvc-170).

Answer (score 3):

On my armv7hl (i.MX6q with linux 4.1.15) system, to set a breakpoint in another process, I use :

ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, pid, address, 0xe7f001f0)

I choose that value after strace'ing gdb :)

This works perfectly : I can examine the traced process, restore the original instruction, and restart the process with PTRACE_CONT.

Comment: is that instruction fix only to armv7 or maybe to arm v4 too?

Comment: Which signal do you get in host process for the ptraced process once the breakpoint is hit?

Answer (score 3):

Although the original question asked about Cortex-A7 which is ARMv7-A, on ARMv8 GDB uses

> *brk #0*

Answer (score 2):

We can use breakpoint inst:

- For A32: use 
  [BRK #imm](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0802a/BRK.html) instruction
- For Arm and Thumb: use [BKPT #imme](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cihbiggi.html) instruction.

Or we can use [UND](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489e/CIHJIJCA.html) pseudo-instruction to generate undefined instruction which will cause exception if processor attempt to execute it.

Comment: In the first bullet item, did you perhaps mean A64, not A32?
And then, I believe the second bullet should be "for A32 and T16"