# How do I implement breakpoints with C on the ARM processor?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, assembly, arm

I am trying to write a debugger for my Raspberry Pi 3 as a learning exercise. It it an ARMv7.

This section of code is how you set the breakpoint on the x86 architecture:

```
if ((orig = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, pid, h.symaddr, NULL)) < 0) {
        perror("PTRACE_PEEKTEXT");
        exit(-1);
      }
      trap = (orig & ~0xff) | 0xcc;
      if (ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, pid, h.symaddr, trap) < 0) {
        perror("PTRACE_POKETEXT");
        exit(-1);
      }
```

Specifically, the line `trap = (orig & ~0xff) | 0xcc;` is how you change the first byte to the opcode of the `int 3` syscall. This sets a breakpoint on the x86. However, I am at a loss on how to do it for ARM. I have tried searching the GDB source files to see how they do, and I have found the *-tdep.c family of files. They have arm-linux-tdep.c and arm-tdep.c. Within these files I found:

```
/* Under ARM GNU/Linux the traditional way of performing a breakpoint
   is to execute a particular software interrupt, rather than use a
   particular undefined instruction to provoke a trap.  Upon exection
   of the software interrupt the kernel stops the inferior with a
   SIGTRAP, and wakes the debugger.  */

‌static const gdb_byte arm_linux_arm_le_breakpoint[] = { 0x01, 0x00, 0x9f, 0xef };

‌static const gdb_byte arm_linux_arm_be_breakpoint[] = { 0xef, 0x9f, 0x00, 0x01 };

/* However, the EABI syscall interface (new in Nov. 2005) does not look at
   the operand of the swi if old-ABI compatibility is disabled.  Therefore,
   use an undefined instruction instead.  This is supported as of kernel
   version 2.5.70 (May 2003), so should be a safe assumption for EABI
   binaries.  */

‌static const gdb_byte eabi_linux_arm_le_breakpoint[] = { 0xf0, 0x01, 0xf0, 0xe7 };

‌static const gdb_byte eabi_linux_arm_be_breakpoint[] = { 0xe7, 0xf0, 0x01, 0xf0 };

/* All the kernels which support Thumb support using a specific undefined
   instruction for the Thumb breakpoint.  */

‌static const gdb_byte arm_linux_thumb_be_breakpoint[] = {0xde, 0x01};

‌static const gdb_byte arm_linux_thumb_le_breakpoint[] = {0x01, 0xde};

/* Because the 16-bit Thumb breakpoint is affected by Thumb-2 IT blocks,
   we must use a length-appropriate breakpoint for 32-bit Thumb
   instructions.  See also thumb_get_next_pc.  */

‌static const gdb_byte arm_linux_thumb2_be_breakpoint[] = { 0xf7, 0xf0, 0xa0, 0x00 };

‌static const gdb_byte arm_linux_thumb2_le_breakpoint[] = { 0xf0, 0xf7, 0x00, 0xa0 };
```

I have tried replacing `trap = (orig & ~0xff) | 0xcc;` with the values from the arm-linux-tdep.c file as so(I use little endian since my system is little endian):

`trap = (orig & ~0xff) | 0x01009fef; // doesn't work`
`trap = (orig & ~0xff) | 0xf001f0e7; // doesn't work`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <elf.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

typedef struct handle {
  Elf64_Ehdr *ehdr;
  Elf64_Phdr *phdr;
  Elf64_Shdr *shdr;
  uint8_t *mem;
  char *symname;
  Elf64_Addr symaddr;
  struct user_regs_struct pt_reg;
  char *exec;
} handle_t;

Elf64_Addr lookup_symbol(handle_t *, const char *);

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
  int fd;
  handle_t h;
  struct stat st;
  long trap, orig;
  int status, pid;
  char * args[2];
  if (argc < 3) {
    printf("Usage: %s <program> <function>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(0);
  }
  if ((h.exec = strdup(argv[1])) == NULL) {
    perror("strdup");
    exit(-1);
  }
  args[0] = h.exec;
  args[1] = NULL;
  if ((h.symname = strdup(argv[2])) == NULL) {
    perror("strdup");
    exit(-1);
  }
  if ((fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
    perror("open");
    exit(-1);
  }
  if (fstat(fd, &st) < 0) {
    perror("fstat");
    exit(-1);
  }
  h.mem = mmap(NULL, st.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
  if (h.mem == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("mmap");
    exit(-1);
  }
  h.ehdr = (Elf64_Ehdr *)h.mem;
  h.phdr = (Elf64_Phdr *)(h.mem + h.ehdr->e_phoff);
  h.shdr = (Elf64_Shdr *)(h.mem + h.ehdr->e_shoff);
  if+ (h.mem[0] != 0x7f || strcmp((char *)&h.mem[1], "ELF")) {
    printf("%s is not an ELF file\n",h.exec);
    exit(-1);
  }
  if (h.ehdr->e_type != ET_EXEC) {
    printf("%s is not an ELF executable\n", h.exec);
    exit(-1);
  }
  if (h.ehdr->e_shstrndx == 0 || h.ehdr->e_shoff == 0 || h.ehdr->e_shnum == 0) {
    printf("Section header table not found\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
  if ((h.symaddr = lookup_symbol(&h, h.symname)) == 0) {
    printf("Unable to find symbol: %s not found in executable\n", h.symname);
    exit(-1);
  }
  close(fd);
  if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
    perror("fork");
    exit(-1);
  }
  if (pid == 0) {
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, pid, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
      perror("PTRACE_TRACEME");
      exit(-1);
    }
    execve(h.exec, args, envp);
    exit(0);
  }
  wait(&status);
  printf("Beginning analysis of pid: %d at %lx\n", pid, h.symaddr);
  if ((orig = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, pid, h.symaddr, NULL)) < 0) {
    perror("PTRACE_PEEKTEXT");
    exit(-1);
  }
  trap = (orig & ~0xff) | 0xcc;
  if (ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, pid, h.symaddr, trap) < 0) {
    perror("PTRACE_POKETEXT");
    exit(-1);
  }
  trace:
  if (ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
    perror("PTRACE_CONT");
    exit(-1);
  }
  wait(&status);
  if (WIFSTOPPED(status) && WSTOPSIG(status) == SIGTRAP) {
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, NULL, &h.pt_reg) < 0) {
      perror("PTRACE_GETREGS");
      exit(-1);
    }
    printf("\nExecutable %s (pid: %d) has hit breakpoint 0x%lx\n",
    h.exec, pid, h.symaddr);
    printf("%%rcx: %llx\n%%rdx: %llx\n%%rbx: %llx\n"
    "%%rax: %llx\n%%rdi: %llx\n%%rsi: %llx\n"
    "%%r8: %llx\n%%r9: %llx\n%%r10: %llx\n"
    "%%r11: %llx\n%%r12 %llx\n%%r13 %llx\n"
    "%%r14: %llx\n%%r15: %llx\n%%rsp: %llx",
    h.pt_reg.rcx, h.pt_reg.rdx, h.pt_reg.rbx,
    h.pt_reg.rax, h.pt_reg.rdi, h.pt_reg.rsi,
    h.pt_reg.r8, h.pt_reg.r9, h.pt_reg.r10,
    h.pt_reg.r11, h.pt_reg.r12, h.pt_reg.r13,
    h.pt_reg.r14, h.pt_reg.r15, h.pt_reg.rsp);
    printf("\nPlease hit any key to continue: ");
    getchar();
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, pid, h.symaddr, orig) < 0) {
      perror("PTRACE_POKETEXT");
      exit(-1);
    }
    h.pt_reg.rip = h.pt_reg.rip - 1;
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, NULL, &h.pt_reg) < 0) {
      perror("PTRACE_SETREGS");
      exit(-1);
    }
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_SINGLESTEP, pid, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
      perror("PTRACE_SINGLESTEP");
      exit(-1);
    }
    wait(NULL);
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, pid, h.symaddr, trap) < 0) {
      perror("PTRACE_POKETEXT");
      exit(-1);
    }
    goto trace;
    }
    if (WIFEXITED(status))
    printf("Completed tracing pid: %d\n", pid);
    exit(0);
  }

  Elf64_Addr lookup_symbol(handle_t *h, const char *symname)
  {
    int i, j;
    char *strtab;
    Elf64_Sym *symtab;
    for (i = 0; i < h->ehdr->e_shnum; i++) {
      if (h->shdr[i].sh_type == SHT_SYMTAB) {
        strtab = (char *)&h->mem[h->shdr[h->shdr[i].sh_link].sh_offset];
        symtab = (Elf64_Sym *)&h->mem[h->shdr[i].sh_offset];
        for (j = 0; j < h->shdr[i].sh_size/sizeof(Elf64_Sym); j++) {
          if(strcmp(&strtab[symtab->st_name], symname) == 0)
          return (symtab->st_value);
          symtab++;
        }
      }
    }
  return 0;
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me implement breakpoints for ARM? I have spent hours researching but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: The `orig & ~0xff` is just because on x86 you want to replace a single byte only. On arm you obviously need more than a single byte, that is `trap = 0x01009fef;` should work better.

Comment: @Jester I have tried that, but it still does not work. It keeps giving me `PTRACE_PEEKTEXT: Success`

Comment: The code is broken, of course `orig` can be negative that doesn't mean an error. This is what `man ptrace` says about it: _Since the value returned by a successful PTRACE_PEEK* request may be -1, the caller must clear errno before the call, and then check it afterward to determine whether  or  not  an  error occurred._

Comment: This may be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345371/how-do-i-set-a-software-breakpoint-on-an-arm-processor