# Portable equivalent of __debugbreak

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I've written some code using `__debugbreak()` on Windows, and I'd like to support other compilers, so I'm looking to create a more portable version of this function (Clang and GCC).

I've rejected using inline assembler for now because it does not provide a target-independent means of specifying a debug break. I've also looked at `__builtin_trap()` but apparently it doesn't really permit for example step in/step over afterwards and that kind of thing. I've also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173618/is-there-a-portable-equivalent-to-debugbreak-debugbreak) but the accepted answer doesn't actually specify the bit that I'm looking for- the bit that goes in the "...".

I've also seen some patches for Clang about supporting this, but apparently Clang still rejected code containing `__debugbreak()`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm that `__builtin_trap()` does not give you the right type of breakpoint to continue in gcc. It gives an `illegal opcode trap`, which doesn't allow the code to continue at all - if you do `next` in gdb, it just exits with a `SIGILL`, which isn't particularly beneficial if you actually wanted to be able to continue.

As far as I can see, the only solution is to use inline assembler. I tried using an `int 3` in a "hello, world" program, and although `gdb` didn't recognise the breakpoint, it did stop at the instruction, and I was able to continue after the break.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BREAKPOINT \
    asm("int $3")

int main()
{

    BREAKPOINT;

    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

(Compiled with both gcc and clang on Linux x86_64, both 32 and 64 bit mode)

I did find this blog:
http://mainisusuallyafunction.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/embedding-gdb-breakpoints-in-c-source.html

but it requires a script to parse the executable file (and may not work under Windows at all).

Comment: Btw you want to use asm("int3"); not asm("int 3"); . The version with a space will not always be compiled to the correct opcode 0xCC. GCC does compile them to the same, but other compilers may not.