# How to setup custom breakpoints in the C++ program?

Tags: c++, linux, build, console

I'm working on a project, where I cannot disclose the details of the code. So, the application is all written in C and C++. Since, a particular file which wanted to debug has a lot of dependencies and exports, I need to debug the whole project. How do I set breakpoints in the code itself so that the debugging would stop at that particular point? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 (since the project is compatible with this environment) and gdb debugger.

I've tried using

```
#include <csignal>

// Generate an interrupt
std::raise(SIGINT);
```

But I keep getting error

```
error: ‘raise’ is not a member of ‘std’
```

Even this also didn't work

```
#include <signal.h>
raise(SIGINT);
```

Plus the debugging wont stop at that point, so that I could foresee the function at that point. I only want to debug it from console, rather using any IDE.

Since the programfile I want to debug has lot many header files which it imports, I'm unable to make a executable to use gdb. So, while `make clean build` of my MakeFile I want to debug the particular program file at a particular function. So, for that I want to add  breakpoints in the program. I cannot use any GUI for debugging since I should not use.

Comment: Your Ubuntu 14 is *really old* and you should upgrade it (current Ubuntu is [18.04](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) in october 2018)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Ikr

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52847568/edit) your question to **add several paragraphs of motivation and context**. Why do you need to add breakpoints inside your C code? Why cannot you run `gdb` non-interactively, with some script (perhaps from your `Makefile`?)? Without these explanations, your question is unclear.

Comment: You set the breakpoints in your debugger, not in the source code.

Comment: Your question is very unclear and shows a lot of confusion. Build your program on the command line. Show the compilation commands and some [MCVE] in your question

Comment: It seems that you are very unfamiliar with best (or even current) practices in C and/or C++. I strongly recommend studying the source code of some small free software applications (perhaps similar to yours) for Linux. You'll find many of them e.g. on [github](http://github.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use GDB Commands?
`b lineno          - set a break point at line 'lineno'
 b srcfile:lineno   - set a break point in source file 'srcfile' at line 'lineno'`

Comment: So I can put this in my program?

Comment: check this link here https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_28.html

Answer (score 0):

Read more about [debugging with `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). Be sure to compile all your code with [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug information (so use `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` to compile it with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)).

GDB is [extensible](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Extending-GDB.html) and you can [define](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html) your own `gdb` commands at [startup](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Startup.html) in your init file, [probably `.gdbinit`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Startup.html#index-_002egdbinit) and put some initial commands there.

BTW, on Linux, debugging (so the `gdb` debugger) is using [ptrace(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) facilities. And you can use `gdb` non-interactively on the command line, using scripts.

> How do I set breakpoints in the code itself

I don't recommend adding specific C code for breakpoints. So **don't do that** in your C code. But see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49079078/841108).

Perhaps you want some backtrace library, like Ian Taylor's [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace) ?

> I cannot use any GUI for debugging

You don't need to. You'll **use `gdb` on the command line.** With an appropriate `gdb` script, you can even use it non-interactively (e.g. in a `Makefile`)

> I only want to debug it from console, rather using any IDE.

Please realize that [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)s are only glorified [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor)s capable of running other *external* tools (including the GCC compiler and the `gdb` debugger). You certainly don't need -on Linux- any IDE to run a compiler or a debugger (but IDEs could be *convenient*, but *not necessary*, for that), because you can (and should) run your compiler, your debugger, your build automation tool, on the command line.

> Since the program file I want to debug has lot many header files which it imports, I'm unable to make a executable

You should fix that first. You need to **make an executable**. BTW, there is no "import" involved at run time, since [header files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive) are relevant only at compile time. Read more about the [`cpp` preprocessor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/). You probably should [invoke GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) (e.g. the `g++` compiler, since you have C++ code) with appropriate [preprocessor options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) (sometimes, tools like [`pkg-config`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) are useful for that). You probably should use some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool such as [GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) ([with](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) *your* `Makefile`; see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108) for inspiration) or [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/). You could add ad hoc `gdb` commands to your build procedure (e.g. with some additional and specific rules and/or recipes in your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile)).

Comment: it is more while building the project itself the program gets debugged, so I wanted to put the breakpoint in the program.

Comment: Wrong approach. Your building procedure should run `gdb`  with an appropriate script. Don't try to add breakpoints programmatically in C. BTW, you might explain why you want to debug your program at build time (it is an usual requirement)

Comment: I have a programfile which is a part of the project, which inturn has many headerfiles to import. So individually I could not make a exe file to use gdb.

Comment: If you don't have an executable, you cannot run a debugger. So you need to improve your build procedures to use executables (even "temporary" ones)

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have compiled with -g.  There are other gdb specific flags in gcc.  You could add them in too.

Try using ddd, the graphical version of gdb.  Great tool if you don't know the gdb command line.  Just open up the relevant source file, select the line then click on breakpoint on the toolbar.  It will tell you on the console section, what command was actually executed (good way to learn).  There is a floating button list with run, next etc. for stepping through your code.

ddd will work on most of the gcc toolchain.

**EDIT:**
Say your code is made up of 2 files main.cpp and child.cpp.  main.cpp contains main().  The executable is called a.out.

To start

```
ddd a.out &
```

It will open in main.cpp.  To put a breakpoint in child.cpp, click on File/Open Source... and select child.cpp.  Then scroll to where you want a breakpoint.  Put your cursor on the line, then click on break in the toolbar.

To run, either type run in the gdb window below or click on Run in the floating button dialog.

Comment: I'm sorry, I want to put the breakpoint in the program itself, right before I debug. Could you help me 'How to put a breakpoint in the program itself'.

Comment: I've modified the answer.