# What is the difference between int3 instruction and call __debugbreak?

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, gdb, interrupt

What is __debugbreak? Is it used for triggering SIGTRAP? What is the difference between int3 and __debugbreak?

Comment: On the platforms that I am familiar with, the two map to the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`int3` is an x86 instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/intn:into:int3:int1).

[`__debugbreak()` is an *intrinsic* supported by MSVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/debugbreak?view=vs-2017) that will get the compiler to emit that instruction when compiling for x86, or whatever software-breakpoint instruction is appropriate for the target ISA (e.g. ARM, AArch64, etc.)

ICC also supports it, but other compilers (like gcc) don't..

You *wouldn't* do `call __debugbreak` in asm, you'd just write `int3`.  e.g. if you compile a function that uses it, like

```
void foo() {
    __debugbreak();
}
```

MSVC on the Godbolt compiler explorer produces this asm:

```
void foo(void) PROC                                        ; foo
    npad    2
    int     3
    ret     0
```

Notice the lack of a `call` instruction anywhere.  It's an intrinsic that "inlines" even with optimization disabled.  It's not "just" a function.

---

This is the same as how `_mm_mfence()` is an intrinsic for the `mfence` instruction, or `_mm_popcnt_u64` for 64-bit operand-size `popcnt`.

---

Related: [Is there a portable equivalent to DebugBreak()/__debugbreak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173618/is-there-a-portable-equivalent-to-debugbreak-debugbreak/49079078#49079078)
says clang has a `__builtin_debugtrap()`.

Another answer there says the more widely available GNU C `__builtin_trap()` is assumed to stop / abort the program, not act like a breakpoint.  (So gcc won't emit any code after an unconditional `__builtin_trap`.)

---

**update: apparently MSVC *does* let you take its address, so I guess there is a library version of it somewhere.**  So you *could* write `call __debugbreak` in asm, but you still *wouldn't* because it's pointless.

GCC does *not* let you take the address of builtins, for example trying to compile:

```
int (*getbuiltin(void))(unsigned) {    return &__builtin_popcount;  }
```

gives you this error:

```
error: built-in function '__builtin_popcount' must be directly called
```

But MSVC and ICC compile `void (*getFunc(void))(void) { return &__debugbreak; }` into this ([on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZugHZEDKqAhgDbYgCMAdAEwAOAJzCALAFYADIIDsohaPIArHuXat6oVAFJ%2BAIT37yAZ3QBXUqi4ByHVICCAN3QFMAajroIASnc7ZQ0d3EPcAfTCcACNzYCjSbFYAa18dAGYghwCAEXssxxc3dwgAKmBsIgAxc3pUCELMHx9610b/QLzQ9wSiS3p/fgA2COjY%2BMSk9MycvNn%2BNIJa9nMcfzSAYQIAWy3FolJF3iR03Dy94rKKgAd0K9RGFrcmiBqTAmB6bDaAzK6evoGwx2YRud0YYXMaX4U1mslyjjmCxoOBo4TCAHEAHIAVXWETOjAu5SIMQI7CIi0ejWar3en2%2BHWCoX%2BpH6emGYVJ5MWINuGBqRBhCLhiOw9EINBsPnUIBsEhs5HosqkCvQsvWRiM7jMlmsAzS3AVRGVUulSRA0hlNjECq2IDEg14skEgwkIkGwjkEgk/FkipN5DVNgVJhAUnIxpsKulcFgKAwWyuZOwFCoEATSc4pBAwEE/HINDJRBToYgUQDUUWrFIAE9ZYbyAmtmKiAB5ejsOtRhU4LaaYCcAOEBKoClObCh7vkbAAD2wqHMxfrCr22HYAfYBHi1Zr6ywtgb%2B22y%2BldEYLA4XD4QlEkhk8kUSg0WjQmoM6i3ocg0tuFIYk4AWlbNJ3AAgB1Dh2BDCwrCvaV1zlBUlSnIMZxdADBjEdxgFQVB3EEARinwYgyH1bhyHcPdE2TUgyL8DUDCMI0TSacgkESHBs18K0bXIO1%2BAkXhBDkATxEECQ0kESRZAkf0UNlEMwwjFjyFjZAQAsIgrkXShqAzGi1C%2BEjs3IgB3UhWCuE8rXlOSVUDWU9ANdxTOIJB3DQwYMKwnC8II/hmO7ViEN4/jZF4KFBm4aRBGil0pG4QY7NVBTTCUyNozNC1wwQtIkIDINAujVTEDUiB43Qais109NKszFMQAIXDuGEcjC3JEtqHLKdK3oHdl0bSrm0YdtOyHbA%2By0Qcp2HecxwnANZ3nRcDxXRg1w3LcLNrPccAGo87RsQ1TwYZg2EHa8RHEGKH0fdR%2B1fRj303KIv2438CH/WVwMg0DgNAkwiEwdJsg%2Bcw330bhZGg3U4Js/L5JsTzvPcJq8Ja3gpF4bgiMIEhaKc8jKLqmj9X4eiIaK002I4hruPNbgpBy2VQuy5KHODNLwwyqUSvgcq0BJ6q030rMQCcVAriuMInBasJErCGdMILItOrLCsq1rAamxbUau3s3t%2B2mg2CBHebJ3spaFyXI61uLBD7Je7bd33faDkO46C1Oi8LoEK67zkR8nwe3QnuMF63p/K4/3oQDW3snVYJ4eDZVs5D7NQzD3C2EwJfcWXhGxwZceMsiKKo%2BqCfmNIKbDqngpZ202fTlLOdDbmWKyy1coRjPUp5hubAC9nCuUoLpXHUg3gYe0gA))

```
void (__cdecl*getFunc(void))(void) PROC                         ; getFunc
    lea     rax, OFFSET FLAT:__debugbreak
    ret     0
```

Comment: __debugbreak is a function. Can you elaborate on why can't we call this in asm?

Comment: @anandthegreat: Updated.  It's not *just* a function, there's never a reason not to inline it as `int3` in asm, unless you're taking the address as a function pointer.  I'm surprised MSVC even has a non-inline version of it in the library.  GCC doesn't let you take the address of built-in functions.

Comment: @PeterCordes ["Some intrinsics are available only as intrinsics, and some are available both in function and intrinsic implementations."](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/compiler-intrinsics?view=vs-2019) However, ["This routine is only available as an intrinsic."](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/debugbreak?view=vs-2019) (and even as far back as VS2015), so IDK. That being said, there is the [`DebugBreak()` Windows API call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms679297.aspx) in `kernel32.dll`, so it's possible there's a stub somewhere in the vcrt…