# Why does my barebone C/C++ model not perform as TensorFlow one?

Tags: python, c++, c, tensorflow, keras

I implemented a regression model (that takes in 3 inputs and adds them at the output) in TensorFlow as:

```
hidden = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=8,
                               input_shape=[3])

output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([hidden, output])

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error')

history = model.fit(xtrain,ytrain,
                    epochs=500,
                    shuffle= True,
                    verbose=False)

print("Finished training the model")
```

And it performs excellently with just 8 training set of data and 500 epochs (By default uses Linear activation and no normalization).

When I try to do the same on a C/C++ low-level model (with only standard C/C++ libraries), with everything the same (Apparently), I get `NAN` for all the weights as well as output.

```
/// Forward pass
            for (int j=0; j<numHiddenNodes; j++)
            {
                double activation=hiddenLayerBias[j];
                //std::cout<<"Training Set :"<<x<<"\n";
                 for (int k=0; k<numInputs; k++) {
                    activation+=training_inputs[x][k]*hiddenWeights[k][j];
                }
                hiddenLayer[j] = lin(activation);
            }

            for (int j=0; j<numOutputs; j++) {
                double activation=outputLayerBias[j];
                for (int k=0; k<numHiddenNodes; k++)
                {
                    activation+=hiddenLayer[k]*outputWeights[k][j];
                }
                outputLayer[j] = lin(activation);
            }

            //std::cout << "Input:" << training_inputs[x][0] << " " << "    Output:" << outputLayer[0] << "    Expected Output: " << training_outputs[x][0] << "\n";
            MSE += (1/numOutputs)*pow( training_outputs[x][0] - outputLayer[0], 2);

           /// Backprop
           ///   For V
            double deltaOutput[numOutputs];
            for (int j=0; j<numOutputs; j++) {
                double errorOutput = (training_outputs[i][j]-outputLayer[j]);
                deltaOutput[j] = errorOutput*dlin(outputLayer[j]);
            }

            ///   For W
            double deltaHidden[numHiddenNodes];
            for (int j=0; j<numHiddenNodes; j++) {
                double errorHidden = 0.0f;
                for(int k=0; k<numOutputs; k++) {
                    errorHidden+=deltaOutput[k]*outputWeights[j][k];
                }
                deltaHidden[j] = errorHidden*dlin(hiddenLayer[j]);
            }

            ///Updation
            ///   For V and b
            for (int j=0; j<numOutputs; j++) {
                //b
                outputLayerBias[j] += deltaOutput[j]*lr;
                for (int k=0; k<numHiddenNodes; k++)
                {
                    outputWeights[k][j]+= hiddenLayer[k]*deltaOutput[j]*lr;
                }
```

The full file can be accessed [here](https://github.com/PrashantDandriyal/Neural-Networks-In-Cpp/blob/master/stack_overflow1.cpp).

I don't seem to know the difference in the performance. By the way, my model works well with other activation functions like **tanh** but I switched to **linear** for experimentation.

Comment: You'll have to debug when the first NaN appears (as it will quickly propagate everywhere). I would assume you divide by zero somewhere, leading to infinities and then NaNs, but that can't be figured out from the information in this question alone.

Comment: It hard to find the element that would cause such a situation. There is only one place where a subtraction occurs and 0 places where a division occurs. I have added 0.001 in case the subtraction gives a 0. But still getting NaN.

Comment: That's exactly why you should bring out the debugger and find the root cause. Just because it's machine learning doesn't mean it's sufficient to fiddle with inputs and code until it "works". I would recommend checking for NaNs after (or in) every loop and using one of the options from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173618/is-there-a-portable-equivalent-to-debugbreak-debugbreak) to make your debugger break at the first occurrence. Then inspect the contents of the arrays and work backwards from there.