# The program has unexpectedly finished

Tags: qt, visual-c++, qt-creator

While running release build in Qt Creator get following error message:

```
The program has unexpectedly finished.
.....exe exited with code -1073740791
```

Runs successfully in debug mode in debugger. In another thread found that this is

```
0xc0000409 = STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN
```

error. Program and Qt was built with VS C++. Where the problem could be? Or should I run some profiler to check memory access?

Comment: first build your code with option: "treat warning as errors" (in gcc it is "-Wall") to catch any stupid problems.

Answer (score 3):

When a program runs in debug, but crashes in release, it tends to be due to uninitialised variables. Debug builds, particularly running with a debugger, may clear the memory for you before use, so it can hide the problem. I suggest you start by checking for uninitialised variables.

If you're really stuck, change the configuration to build debug symbols for the release build, then when it crashes attach a debugger and see what the code is doing.

Alternatively, print out debug text to the console with [qDebug](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdebug.html) at various points in your code and see if you can identify where the problem is from that.

Comment: Have not found uninitialized variables. Can't attach debugger as it exits immediately. I've added  std::cerr << "program start" << endl; output on program start - outputs nothing.

Comment: You can try placing a break in code at the start of your main function. In gcc/clang that would be: __asm__("int $3"); The syntax may be slightly different for VSC++. Once the break has been hit, you can then attach the debugger. There's more about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37299/xcode-equivalent-of-asm-int-3-debugbreak-halt

Comment: Seems it even does not go to main(). Weird: works fine now on one machine after full clean/rebuild, still fails on another.

Comment: Check system logs and see if there's any clue there as to what's going wrong.

Comment: Debugger shows it fails in QtXml4!QDomNode::toElement. But why it not fails in debug?! Tried to output trace to log, still no info...

Comment: Look around everything to do with your xml code; there's likely to be something getting used before being initialised. How are you outputting "trace to log" ?

Comment: Own logger class with fprintf within

Comment: to a file and to stderr in case I logging error. Now only to a file. I even put try/catch in block where I think it fails - nothing, do not catch. May be some access violation error? Is there some good profiler ala valgrind in Windows for VS C++?

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with Windows alternative profiler, though it looks like it has been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows

Comment: @AlekseyKontsevich This sounds to me like a missing DLL, especially the part about the program not entering main(). Check a couple things: 1) That any DLLs your program may use are in the working directory, and 2) that the working directory of your program is where you think it is (check your IDE's settings).

Comment: I checked with DependencyWalker - all dlls are present.